# Externalize properties for Oozie workflows in Cloudera

Tags: cloudera, oozie, hue

we are developing dozens of different workflows in Oozie. We use 3 environments, DEV, PRE and PRO.

What I'd like to do is to keep same workflow.xml files in all 3 environments and only read properties for db connections, urls, authentications etc from the Cloudera environment. In this way, it would be possible to version control the files and deploy them easily. Is it possible?

Googling, I saw maybe config-default.xml would be a place for default property values, but I cannot find any in our Cloudera 5.10. We use Hue to design the workflows, algthough we can use other way to define WFs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use job properties to achieve this.

```
oozie job -oozie http://localhost:11000/oozie -config dev.properties -run
```

If you set a property as `queueName=devqueue` in your `dev.properties` file, you can refer to it in the workflow.xml as `${queueName}`

Please note that job properties file is a **local file**, not in HDFS. You can get more details about this in https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.0.0/DG_Examples.html.

Comment: Hi Lan, thanks for the reply. 
The thing is that our client wants to have some graphical interface like Hue, so they could control (including launching) any job in the datalake.

Maybe we could edit externally job.properties in the WF's workspace? Actually I've tried to edit the contents of the file, but Hue ignores the new values - when submitting, a popup opens with all the properties with values unchanged. Maybe I'm doing something wrong?